# Override function with a derived argument

Tags: c#, inheritance

I want to hold number of derived classes in an array as their base class.
Then loop over the array and have the derived classes invoke a function which receive the same DB, but each derived class should receive the DB as a different Interface.

Is there another way to implement such a case?

That what I tried to do, but the override can't find a suitable virtual function:

```
public interface IBase
{

}
public interface IClass1 : IBase
{
    bool[] IsEnable { get; }
}

public interface IClass2 : IBase
{
    bool[] IsEnable { set; }
}

public class DB : IBase, IClass1, IClass2
{
    public bool[] IsEnable { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Base
{
    public virtual void fRun(IBase p_oOb)
    {

    }
}

class MyClass1 : Base
{
    public override void fRun(IClass1 p_oOb)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MyClass1 fRun.");
    }
}

class MyClass2 : Base
{
    public override void fRun(IClass2 p_oOb)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MyClass2 fRun.");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DB db = new DB();
        Base[] classes = new Base[] {new MyClass1(), new MyClass2()};
        foreach (var Class in classes)
        {
            Class.fRun(db);
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: why can't you cast `IBase` as desired interface inside overriden bodies?

Comment: I can do that.. but in such case  myClassx has permission to the entire DB and it's up to it to a lower its own permission/accessibility.

Comment: Isn't it the case as long as `IClassx` inherits from `IBase`? Maybe create another, fake interface just to have a base for the argument.

Comment: IBase is the fake interface.

Answer (score 0):

This code won't compile:

```
class MyClass1 : Base
{
    public override void fRun(IClass1 p_oOb)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MyClass1 fRun.");
    }
}
```

It throws:

> MyClass1.fRun(IClass1) No suitable method to override

You can't override a base class function which is actually different than the function in the base class.

- If `IClass1`, `IClass2` derive from `IBase` (as they are) then just
  have the signature with the `IBase` and pass a derived.
- If they will not always derive, if they have different functions you'd like to execute in the concrete type or if you want specific classes to receive specific IBase then  make it generic and `fRun` will get a `TBase`. In that case you will also probably need some extra abstraction to pass the correct `IBase` to each `Base`

Fixing your code according to option 1 it'll be: *(also notice that the `IsEnable` is now in `IBase`)*

```
public interface IBase
{
    bool[] IsEnable { get; }
}
public interface IClass1 : IBase { }

public interface IClass2 : IBase { }

public class DB : IBase
{
    public bool[] IsEnable { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Base
{
    public virtual void fRun(IBase p_oOb) { }
}

class MyClass1 : Base
{
    public override void fRun(IBase p_oOb)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MyClass1 fRun.");
    }
}

class MyClass2 : Base
{
    public override void fRun(IBase p_oOb)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MyClass2 fRun.");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DB db = new DB();
        Base[] classes = new Base[] { new MyClass1(), new MyClass2() };
        foreach (var Class in classes)
        {
            Class.fRun(db);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your override in the `MyClass1` and `MyClass2` respectively needs to look like this:

```
public override void fRun(IBase p_oOb)
{

}
```

Otherwise it will not override the initial virtual method.

You can use the overriden method to call a private method in each class:

```
public override void fRun(IBase p_oOb)
{
    if(p_oOb is IMyClass1) // or IMyClass2 respectively
        private_fRun(p_oOb);
}
```

Btw. you should use `abstract`-Keyword on the method if you do not plan to implement anything within the abstact base class. That way, your derived classes are required to implement it.

Also, your classes inherit just from `Base`. Should they not also implement the interfaces `IClass1` and `IClass2`. Just out of curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use:

```
class C
{
    private MyClass1 _1 = new MyClass1();
    private MyClass2 _2 = new MyClass2();

    public void fRun(IClass1 p_oOb1, IClass2 p_oOb2)
    {
        _1.fRun(p_oOb1);
        _2.fRun(p_oOb2);
    }
}
```

Class `C` doesn't inherit `Base` because:

```
fRun(IBase p_oOb)
```

Is different from:

```
fRun(IClass1 p_oOb1, IClass2 p_oOb2)
```

If it did inherit it, the compiler would throw an error.